# What does this syntax means in scala [H <: Service[H]]

Tags: scala, f-bounded-polymorphism

I'm newer working on a trait then I found this syntax that I didn't understand

```
trait Holder[H <: service.SealedHolder[H]] {
    val personId: String //ID.03
}
```

I guess that may be a generic declaration but still confused about this scala syntax `Holder[H <: service.SealedHolder[H]]`

Comment: If you are familiar with Java: `interface Holder<H extends SealedHolder<H>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it's a generic declaration that `H` is a subtype of `SealedHolder[H]`.

You can read about type bounds
https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/scala-type-bounds/
and F-bounded polymorphism
https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

For example F-bounds are used with trait `Ordered` https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/math/Ordered.html

```
case class OrderedClass(n:Int) extends Ordered[OrderedClass] {
  def compare(that: OrderedClass) = this.n - that.n
}
```